# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<HelloProps>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to inject to stores into a component, but it seems that it's not working.
Here is the class

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

import { FlightStore } from '../stores/FlightStore';

export interface HelloProps {
   flightStore: FlightStore
}



@inject('flightStore')
@observer
class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, any> {

constructor(props: HelloProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        //
    }
}


componentWillMount() {
    this.props.flightStore.getData();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Hello;
```

It says `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<HelloProps>'.
  Property 'flightStore' is missing in type '{}'`, it confuses me because I'm not declaring any data type anywhere so I don't know what's happening.

Here is the store

```
import { action, observable } from 'mobx';
import *  as $ from 'jquery' ;


export class FlightStore {

@observable dataJ: any;

constructor() {
    //
}

@action getData() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.kayak.com/h/mobileapis/directory/airlines',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: (data: any) => {
            this.dataJ = data;
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: (xhr: any, status: any, err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
    console.log('I´m in getData')
}

}
```

It's strange because when I try to put "?" in the class

```
export interface HelloProps {
  flightStore?: FlightStore
}
```

it says that this this.props.flightStore => `[ts] Object is possibly 'undefined'.` in ComponentWillMount()

### Update

And yes the error happens when I try to use `<Hello/>` component without passing props, because I'm using Mobx.
The index app

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Hello from './components/Hello';

import stores from './stores'; 
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';


 export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
        <Provider {...stores}>
            <div>
                <Hello />
            </div>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the original error occurred when you tried to use the component as `<Hello/>` without passing props.  `Hello` is declared as requiring a `flightStore` prop.  You would hope that `@inject` would provide it and TypeScript would know that you don't have to pass it yourself, but that doesn't seem to be working.  So look at the [declaration of `@inject`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/cf039d3be74604c7bd61926904606380f080dac3/src/index.d.ts#L37-L45):

```
// Ideally we would want to return React.ComponentClass<Partial<P>>,
// but TS doesn't allow such things in decorators, like we do in the non-decorator version
// See also #256
export function inject(
    ...stores: string[]
): <T extends IReactComponent>(target: T) => T & IWrappedComponent<T>
export function inject<S, P, I, C>(
    fn: IStoresToProps<S, P, I, C>
): <T extends IReactComponent>(target: T) => T & IWrappedComponent<T>
```

And if you go to the [referenced issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/256), you'll find that the problem is unsolved and there are some suggested workarounds.  One of them is to declare the prop as optional, as you did in the second version, and then use a non-null assertion when accessing it: `this.props.flightStore!`.

Comment: Yes the problem with the "?" in the props is "TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<HelloProps>'.
  Property 'flightStore' is missing in type '{}'.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile."

Comment: Sorry the previos comment was wrong.. When i add the ? the problem turns to be                                       
   "[ts] Object is possibly 'undefined'.
(property) React.Component<HelloProps, any, any>.props: Readonly<{
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}> & Readonly<HelloProps>" to this.props.flightStore

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  It's best if you edit them directly into your question; I've done so this time and you can now delete your answer.  The essence of the answer is still the same: use one of the workarounds from [here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/256) such as making the prop optional and using a non-null assertion when accessing it.